# Set featured image using wp_insert_post

Tags: php, wordpress

```
// Auto post ( Unique File Date ).
$postData = array(
    'post_category' => array( $Category ),
    'post_status' => $Post_Status,
    'post_type' => $Post_Type
);
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $postData );

$getImageFile = 'http://localhost/Multisite/test2/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/Auto Post/twitter.png';

$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $postData, $getImageFile, $post_id );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $getImageFile );

wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
```

The code above make a post successfully but it is not setting the post featured image. I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: The `$postData` should be different for `wp_insert_post` (a *post* post) and `wp_insert_attachment` (an *attachment* post).

Comment: what it should be then?

Comment: See my answer and try it out. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use different `$postData` for the attachment:

```
$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( $getImageFile, null );

$attachment_data = array(
    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
    'post_title' => sanitize_file_name( $getImageFile ),
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit'
);

$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment_data, $getImageFile, $post_id );
```

Currently you're passing the identical post data to the post and its attachment post.

Comment: and also your `$getImageFile` variable must be the file path to your upload directory.  Check the example on the codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment

Comment: `$upload_dir[ 'baseurl' ]` ot `$upload_dir[ 'path' ]` or `$upload_dir[ 'basedir' ]`? which one?

Comment: tell me why use Use different `$postData`? i am not clear with this. thankyou

Comment: `$upload_dir[ 'path' ]` will do the job

Comment: `wp_insert_post` and `wp_insert_attachment` both create a new "post" into the WordPress `posts` table. Attachments are a post type similar to posts or nav menus/items.

Answer (score 1):

I use the function `wp_upload_bits` is new WordPress function for easy for uploading image. On the second line of my code `$post` is your `$post_id` id and for upload file directory I create custom folder that is `custom-uploads` for your better understanding or you can remove that on my 4th line of coding that is `'./'. 'custom-uploads' . '/'`

```
$upload = wp_upload_bits($_FILES["file"]["name"], null, file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]));

$post_id = $posts; //set post id to which you need to set post thumbnail
$filename = $upload['file'];
$uploadfile = $uploaddir['basedir'] . '/'. 'custom-uploads' . '/';

move_uploaded_file($filename, $uploadfile);  // (file name , designation)

$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
$attachment = array(
    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
    'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($filename),
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit'
);
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $posts );
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );

wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );  // set post thumnail (featured image) for the given post
```

Comment: what is `$uploaddir` here?

Comment: @yasaryousuf your base directry path